# C - dynamically sized array of struct pointers in another struct, segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have segfault while trying to run such code.

```
struct list;
struct node;

typedef struct list {
    struct node ** links;
    int size;
    int content;
} list;

typedef struct node {

    wchar_t value;
    struct list* children;
    int exists;

} node;


node* newNode(wchar_t value, int exists) {
    node *q = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    q->value = value;
    q->children = newList();
    q->exists = exists;
    return q;
}

list* newList(){

    list *result = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    result->size = 2;
    result->content = 0;
    result->links = (struct node**) malloc(result->size * sizeof(struct node*));

    return result;

}

void resizeList(list* list_pointer){

    if(list_pointer->size <= list_pointer->content){

        list_pointer->size *= 2;
        list_pointer->links = (struct node**) realloc(list_pointer->links, (list_pointer->size) * sizeof(struct node*));

    }
}

void pushList(list* list_pointer, node* node_pointer){
    if(node_pointer == NULL)
        return;

    resizeList(list_pointer);
    list_pointer->content++;

    int i;
    node* temp_pointer;

    for(i = 0; i < list_pointer->content; i++){

        if(list_pointer->links[i] == NULL){
            list_pointer->links[i] = node_pointer;
            break;
        }

        if(list_pointer->links[i]->value > node_pointer->value){
            temp_pointer = list_pointer->links[i];
            list_pointer->links[i] = node_pointer;
            node_pointer = temp_pointer;
        }
    }

}
```

Calling.

```
struct list* l = newList();

struct node* n1 = newNode(L'a', 1);
struct node* n2 = newNode(L'b', 1);
struct node* n3 = newNode(L'c', 1);
struct node* n4 = newNode(L'd', 1);
struct node* n5 = newNode(L'e', 1);
struct node* n6 = newNode(L'f', 1);
struct node* n7 = newNode(L'g', 1);
struct node* n8 = newNode(L'h', 1);

pushList(l, n1);
pushList(l, n2);
pushList(l, n3);
pushList(l, n4);
pushList(l, n5);
pushList(l, n6);
pushList(l, n7);
pushList(l, n8);
```

After first two pushes it fails.

It's supposed to create list based on values stored in nodes. But... it doesn't. It throws segfault. When I changed allocation of memory from "sizeod(node*)" to "sizeof(node)", it works, but presumably cause of allocation of bigger memory. I want to store POINTERS, not STRUCTS in this array.

I'm figthing that 6 hours with no idea what to do.

Comment: First of all, please put all of your code in one only snippet. And then add the code calling these functions

Comment: Rather confusing way of doing linked lists.

Comment: It's not supposed to be linked lists - I want to search then O(log n), so I need them as an array, to binsearch. And, as you see, I am sorting them.

Comment: I think I see your problem, you are allocating (and reallocating) `list_pointer->links`, and after doing that you simply assume all pointers in that array will be `NULL`. That is a mistake, newly allocated memory is not implicitly zeroed, your code will attept to use those faulty pointers and crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a segfault, then you should include the backtrace in your question.  That will make it a lot easier to figure out what's going on.

Looking at the code, I see that you're not clearing `result->links` when you malloc or realloc it, but you are relying on the pointers being NULL inside `pushList`.  You increase `list_pointer->content` and then check `if (list_pointer->links[i] == NULL)`.  That's going to result in undefined behavior for sure.

Memory is not filled with zeros when you use malloc or realloc.  If you need that to be the case, you need to do it yourself.  (You could use calloc as a replacement for malloc, but that doesn't help you with the realloc.)

This code is fine if you are learning, though I agree with the comment above that it's a bit of a convoluted way of doing it.  If this is for production code then you should use an open-source list library because that will already be debugged and tuned for you.